# iperf3 error exactly 7 seconds into running the test

Tags: networking, network-monitoring, iperf

I am running an iperf test to measure bandwidth from a host iperf client to a container iperf server.Exactly 7 seconds into the test iperf gives an error &  abruptly ends the test. The message says " iperf3: error - received an unknown control message" Please see the screenshot below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzpYY.jpg
Would you know why this is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your client is running iperf3 while your server is running iperf, or vice versa. Ensure both run iperf3.